# Reclaiming questions from the guitar site

Tags: support, status-completed, migration, user-accounts

I had one question (which was answered) on the guitar site: [Is it safe to use guitar polish everywhere on the guitar?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/1595/)

The link no longer works, but I found [the question here on the music site](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/2166/is-it-safe-to-use-guitar-polish-everywhere-on-the-guitar) using the search function. I created a user with the same name and same OpenID login. However, the question is not associated with my new user account. Can this be resolved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found 2 posts from you:

- [Is it safe to use guitar polish everywhere on the guitar?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/2166/is-it-safe-to-use-guitar-polish-everywhere-on-the-guitar)
- [What are the objective differences between the guitar and the piano?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/1904/what-are-the-objective-differences-between-the-guitar-and-the-piano)

Both are now associated to your account, and I did a reputation recalc for you so that the additional rep was picked up.

Comment: Thank you! I don't even remember I had two questions :-)